# Print out userinput 1 ,2 ,3 , Array,Java,Eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string, printing

I'm trying to make a program that asks the user to type in 3 cities and the program
is supposed to take the 3 cities , and put them in a String Array , the first city in
[0],second in [1] and third in [2] , I got it to ask for them , collect the answers
but it's only Printing out the first answer, not all 3. Any ideas how I can fix that?

My code looks like this atm

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String ans;   
    String[] favoritStad = new String [3];
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("skriv in 3 favoritstäder");
    String Användarinlägg1 = scanner1.nextLine();
    String Användarinlägg2 = scanner1.nextLine();
    String Användarinlägg3 = scanner1.nextLine();

    favoritStad[0] = Användarinlägg1;
    favoritStad[1] = Användarinlägg1;
    favoritStad[2] = Användarinlägg1;


    System.out.print(Användarinlägg1);  

}
```

Användarinlägg is userinputt , favorit stad is favcity 
the string "ans" was just an idea I tried to make to collect all 3 answers and print it out
but never figured it out

Solved it ! Just needed to add

```
System.out.print(Användarinlägg2);
System.out.print(Användarinlägg3);
```

Comment: try using a `for` loop

Comment: A hint: I wouldn't use anything but ASCII for any code. Just causes pain in the --- you know where...

Comment: hahahaha well im trying to learn java eclipse thanks for advice tho !

Answer (score 2):

As I suggested in my comment below your question - use a `for` loop. Also always check twice if you are not using the same variable (for example `Användarinlägg1`) over and over.

```
favoritStad[0] = Användarinlägg1;
favoritStad[1] = Användarinlägg2;
favoritStad[2] = Användarinlägg3;

for(int i=0; i<favoritStad.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(favoritStad[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you've added the **same** element 3 times.

You need to use:

```
favoritStad[0] = Användarinlägg1;
favoritStad[1] = Användarinlägg2;
favoritStad[2] = Användarinlägg3;
```

And in order to print you can use for loop or just:

```
System.out.print(favoritStad[0]);
System.out.print(favoritStad[1]);
System.out.print(favoritStad[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop to print all the values of an array. You can use something like below:

```
for (int i=0; i<favoritStad.length();i++){
    System.out.println(favoritStad[i])
}
```

Comment: thats to advanced for me i dont understand Everything in there :D solved it anywa with simply spaming same option as system,outprint first userinput

Answer (score 0):

*Try this way*

```
favoritStad[1] = Användarinlägg2;
favoritStad[2] = Användarinlägg3;
```

*Now Print Array:*

*1st way :*

```
for(int i=0; i<favoritStad.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(favoritStad[i]);
}
```

*2nd way:*

```
 for(String s :favoritStad) {
      System.out.println(s);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to print...

```
System.out.print(favoritStad);
```

instead of

```
System.out.print(Användarinlägg1);
```